# How do I connect to a SQL Server database from CodeIgniter 3?

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I am trying to connect a CodeIgniter 3 project to SQL Server 2008 on a web server running with WAMP.

I have tried connecting to the database with sqlsrv, odbc and pdo dbdrivers but unable to do it still.

Here's what I have tried so far,

1. Installed the sqlsrv drivers for PHP and installed them.
2. `sqlsrv` and `pdo_sqlsrv` show up on the WAMP localhost page, and phpinfo() page

[image]

This is my database.php file,

```php
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => '172.20.15.52',
    'username' => 'ivrserver',
    'password' => 'ivrserver',
    'database' => 'HMS-Migration',
    'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE

);
```

However I get this error on every page of the project,

```
A Database Error Occurred

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
Filename: C:/wamp64/www/ghms/system/database/DB_driver.php
Line Number: 436
```

I tried to use ODBC connector. I made a system DNS from ODBC data sources that connects to the SQL Server database and change the database.php in the following way,

```php
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'mssqltest',
    'username' => 'ivrserver',
    'password' => 'ivrserver',
    'database' => 'HMS-Migration',
    'dbdriver' => 'odbc',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

This is able to connect the database but turns out the [Query Builder doesn't work with ODBC](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/pull/5197). ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

I then turned to try pdo to connect to the SQL Server and made the following changes to database.php

```php
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => 'sqlsrv:server=172.20.15.52,1433;Database=HMS-Migration',
    'hostname' => '',
    'username' => 'ivrserver',
    'password' => 'ivrserver',
    'database' => '',
    'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

This asks me to install the sql drivers for PHP but I think I have them already!

```
A Database Error Occurred

SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x64: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712

Filename: C:/wamp64/www/ghms/system/database/drivers/pdo/pdo_driver.php
Line Number: 142
```

I went back to check my driver installation,

1. I have php 7.0.32 x64 with thread safety enabled
2. Checked C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.32\ext for correct .dll

```
php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
```

3. Checked php.ini file

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
```

4. Both extensions show up in the tray menu of wamp as enabled PHP extensions

### Question,

Although I have checked things to the best of my ability since it still doesn't connect to the database -- i must be wrong somewhere. What is the correct way to connect a CodeIgniter 3 project to SQL Server?

### Edit

I think I found the solution. The error on pdo dbdriver was asking me to install the ODBC Driver for MS SQL but I instead checked for the PHP driver for MS SQL. I went the link in the error, downloaded the ODBC driver and it seems to work now! Silly me!

Answer (score 0):

try this.define your sqlsrv:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'mssqltest',
    'username' => 'ivrserver',
    'password' => 'ivrserver',
    'database' => 'HMS-Migration',
    'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: Hi, I was able to get the project to work using pdo. Please see the edit above.

BTW, I checked these settings too and it still gives the database error. Not sure why putting ODBC system dsn with sqlsrv as dbdriver will work anyway.